# How to move a python application to another folder in server without damaging it?

Tags: python, linux, django, celery

I am running the celery flower application (https://github.com/mher/flower) in my server. I installed this application in my Python LAMP server using the following command:

```
pip install flower
```

Now I want to do some modifications in the application such as functionality and layout. I want to do it by placing a copy of the application files in my `/var/www/html` public folder where all of my other applications are placed so as not to disturb the original application and not having to go into the system files like `../lib/......./dist/flower`. I have been developing applications in django previously and and in django, we can just put a copy of application files in our root applications folder and do modifications in it and the system reads the new copy of the files instead of original installation (pretty clean and clear method). I was hoping to have something like this for this application also? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, none of your application files should be in  /var/www/html. That's for documents served directly by the webserver, not for code.

To answer your question though, if you want to modify a project you should fork it on github, make your changes there, and install from the forked repo in pip.